# search for a string and print next to that using sed/awk?

Tags: sed, awk, centos

i am newbie to `sed/awk` scripts.
i want to search for a string and if matches then print next word to that.

i.e  my output is `RXpackets:1000` and `TXpackets:2000`.

Using `sed/awk` script i want to search, and store values `RXpackets` and `TXpackets` values into variables. That means `1000` and `2000` values. can anybody help me please ?

Also suggest me which script `awk/sed` is best to learn and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to fetch the values from `/proc/net/dev` instead of pulling them out with `ifconfig` etc.

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/sh
iface=eth0
read RXp TXp <<< $(grep $iface /proc/net/dev | awk '{ print $3, $11 }')

echo "$RXp packages received"
echo "$TXp packages sent"
```

Comment: it's cool one. thank you. But, in my case it's taking $2 and $10 values respectively .. Anyways thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. You was looking for R/TXpackets which are represented in columns 3 and 11. Columns 2 and 10 representing the number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the line and when you find the keywords you capture the next word to it.

```
... | awk -F: '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/RXpackets|TXpackets/) print $i"="$(i+1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/[RT]Xpackets/s/.*[RT]Xpackets: *\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Since this just prints the numbers, you can't tell which is which. You could use separate commands for RXpackets and TXpackets to get them by themselves (changing the lines is left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: It's working for me with the sample data you gave. Is there a space after the colon? You didn't show it.

Comment: Are they on the same line or different lines?

Comment: both are in diff lines.. -Barmar

Comment: Updated it to match just one on a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl for this:

```
perl -lne 'push @a,/[RT]Xpackets:(\d+)/g;END{print "@a"}'
```

tested below:

```
> echo "my output is RXpackets:1000 and TXpackets:2000" | perl -lne 'push @a,/[RT]Xpackets:(\d+)/g;END{print "@a"}'
1000 2000
>
```

In what format do you need the output?